# Mudar o nome da url com o conteúdo do banco de dados

Tags: php, htaccess

Como faço para mudar o nome da `url` com o conteúdo do banco de dados em `PHP` usando o `mod_rewrite`?

Por exemplo: Eu tenho no banco uma tabela com o nome das `urls` e quero utilizar isso da seguinte maneira. Vamos supor que em meu site tenho uma página **orçamento**. Cada nome que estiver cadastrado no `bd` eu pego e jogo em uma variável ai ele cria um tipo de url alternativa, porém nunca sai da mesma página. No final ficaria mais ou menos assim.

url padrao: `orcamento`

url customizada: `joao.orcamento` `maria.orcamento`

Comment: Tenta usar a função [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) na variável global `$_GET`

Comment: Pra que usar rewrite pra coisa que o PHP tem nativo? Basta apontar todos os subdominios para o mesmo script e olhar o nome do host na global $_SERVER

Answer (score 1):

em um arquivo .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^orcamento orcamento.php # caso queria que /orcamento também responda
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.orcamento orcamento.php?nome=$1
```

orcamento.php:

```
$nome = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "nome"); // ou $nome = $_GET["nome"];
echo $nome;
/// aqui você pode verificar se o nome está no banco e responder com 200 OK ou 404 Not Found
// com o nome você pode pegar os dados do orçamento e mostrar ao usuário
```

Answer (score -1):

independente do método que você for imprimir a sua url, basta concatenar a url padrão com a url trazida do banco.
$campoUrlBanco = mysql->campo.

//url padrao: orcamento

$padraoUrl= orcamento;

url customizada: $campoUrlBanco'./$padraoUrl